# Itextpdf setting for horizontal scaling is invalid

Tags: java, itext

When I used the itextpdf framework to insert text in a PDF file, I found that horizontal scaling was not effective. Whether additional Settings are required to take effect.

```
PdfContentByte pdfContentByte = this.stamper.getOverContent(1);
pdfContentByte.beginText();
Float left = new Float(UnitConv.mm2pt(11));
Float top = new Float(UnitConv.mm2pt(108));
pdfContentByte.setCharacterSpacing(0);
pdfContentByte.setWordSpacing(0);
String text = "C015849";
pdfContentByte.showTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_LEFT, text, left,top, 0);
pdfContentByte.setHorizontalScaling(80);
pdfContentByte.setTextRenderingMode(PdfContentByte.TEXT_RENDER_MODE_STROKE);
pdfContentByte.endText();
```

If it works, I think the overall width of the string will be smaller and the individual characters will be thinner

---

### The 2018-9-6 solution:

**for horizontal scaling before drawing the text**

```
PdfContentByte pdfContentByte = this.stamper.getOverContent(1);
pdfContentByte.setHorizontalScaling(labelContent.getHorizontalScaling());
pdfContentByte.setLineWidth(15);
pdfContentByte.setTextRenderingMode(PdfContentByte.TEXT_RENDER_MODE_FILL_STROKE);
pdfContentByte.beginText();
```

---

Comment: Shouldn't the scaling come before the text?

Comment: Indeed, setting the scaling and the rendering mode influences text drawn thereafter.

Comment: @mkl@Paulo Soares Thanks for the tip, I've solved it, as you said, for horizontal scaling before drawing the text
···
PdfContentByte pdfContentByte = this.stamper.getOverContent(1);
pdfContentByte.setHorizontalScaling(labelContent.getHorizontalScaling());
pdfContentByte.setLineWidth(15);
pdfContentByte.setTextRenderingMode(PdfContentByte.TEXT_RENDER_MODE_FILL_STROKE);
pdfContentByte.beginText();
···

Comment: Great! Please make that an actual answer (in contrast to a mere comment as it is now) and accept it (by clicking the tick at its upper left after some time).